# verify that a json field exists with jq and bash?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a script that uses jq for parsing a json string `MESSAGE` (that is read from another application). Meanwhile the json has changed and a field is split in 2 fields: `file_path` is now split into `folder` and `file`. The script was reading the `file_path`, now the `folder` may not be present, so for creating the path of the file I have to verify if the field is there. I have search for a while on the internet, and manage to do:

```
echo $(echo $MESSAGE | jq .folder -r)$'/'$(echo $MESSAGE | jq .file -r)

if [ $MESSAGE | jq 'has(".folder")' -r  ]
then
        echo $(echo $MESSAGE | jq .folder -r)$'/'$(echo $MESSAGE | jq .file -r)
else
        echo $(echo $MESSAGE | jq .file -r)
fi
```

where `MESSAGE='{"folder":"FLDR","file":"fl"}'` or `MESSAGE='{"file":"fl"}'`

The first line is printing `FLDR/fl` or `null/fl` if the folder field is not present. So I have thought to create an if that is verifying if the folder field is present or not, but it seems that I am doing it wrong and cannot figure out what is wrong. The output is

```
bash: [: missing `]'
jq: ]: No such file or directory
null/fl
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd do the whole thing in a `jq` filter:

```
echo "$MESSAGE" | jq -r '[ .folder, .file ] | join("/")'
```

In the event that you want to do it with bash (or to learn how to do this sort of thing in bash), two points:

- Shell variables should almost always be quoted when they are used (i.e., `"$MESSAGE"` instead of `$MESSAGE`). You will run into funny problems if one of the strings in your JSON ever contains a shell metacharacter (such as `*`) and you forgot to do that; the string will be subject to shell expansion (and that `*` will be expanded into a list of files in the current working directory).
- A shell `if` accepts as condition a command, and the decision where to branch is made depending on the exit status of that command (true if the exit status is `0`, false otherwise). The `[` you attempted to use is just a command (an alias for `test`, see `man test`) and not special in any way.

So, the goal is to construct a command that exits with `0` if the JSON object has a `folder` property, non-zero otherwise. `jq` has a `-e` option that makes it return `0` if the last output value was not `false` or `null` and non-zero otherwise, so we can write

```
if echo "$MESSAGE" | jq -e 'has("folder")' > /dev/null; then
    echo "$MESSAGE" | jq -r '.folder + "/" + .file'
else
    echo "$MESSAGE" | jq -r .file
fi
```

The `> /dev/null` bit redirects the output from `jq` to `/dev/null` (where it is ignored) so that we don't see it on the console.

Comment: Shall I install something, because the -e is not recognized?

Comment: What version of `jq` are you using?

Comment: `-e` was introduced with 1.4, apparently. If you have an older `jq` version, you could use `if [ "$(echo "$MESSAGE" | jq 'has("folder")')" == "true" ]; then` instead. `$()` is replaced with the output of the command in it; this is a form of process substitution. Again, though, I'd do the whole thing in a `jq` filter and scrap the shell `if`.

Comment: And if I have a "subjson", like `MESSAGE='{"field":{"folder":"F", "file":"f"}}'`, how shall I do it? In fact, how does `has` change?

Comment: `jq '.field | has("folder")'`. Or `jq -r '.field | [ .folder, .file ] | join("/")'`, to do it in one go.